# mb_ereg_replace get the matches

Tags: php, preg-replace

I just want to know, what are the replacements of the preg_replace function.

Is there a possibility to get this?

For Example:

```
$string = "test text 12345"; 

$string = mb_ereg_replace('#text|test#', '$1-test2',$string);
```

I want to know, that "text", and "test" was matched? Or is calling preg_match absoulutely necessary ?

Comment: Do you want to match or replace? Or do you want to know if it actually replaced anything? If so, you could compare $string before and after the replace.

Comment: I want to replace, and match the replacements... But for me its looks not good when i call the replace and the match function, because i think they do the same => matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass by reference a count variable into preg_replace which will return the number of matches/replacements that occurred.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

```
$string = "test text 12345";
$count = 0;
$string = preg_replace('text', 'test2', $string, -1, $count);
echo $count; // 1
```

Comment: Note that this answer was for the original preg_replace question

Comment: Thanks, but it does not deliver the matched phrases. :)

Comment: @maka I'm not sure I understand. You know what the matched phrase was: `test`. FYI, I suggest you delete this question since the changes you've made to it have invalidated all of the answers given.

Answer (score 0):

Well...you could use `preg_replace_callback()` instead, which would enable you to have a custom function called for every match. Then you would be able to "see" the match as well as replacing it the way you want to.

Comment: Thanks, but I am using mb_ereg_replace, and i can't find a mb_ereg_replace_callback function...

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a pattern you are trying to find, but just text within a string, you can use `strstr`.

```
 $findthis = "Apple";
 $container = "Apple Orange Kiwi";

 if (strstr($container,$findthis))
    echo $findthis.' is present';
 else
    echo 'Not found';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match()` to test and then `preg_replace()` if you want to get problems with `preg_replace_callback()` which is also a solution.

Answer (score 0):

*If* all you want to do is:

1. Replace with a simple string (e.g., `text` → `test2`) *and*
2. Find out whether anything was replaced.

In that case I'd simply use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace, followed by [`strcmp()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) to tell whether the string changed (i.e., a replacement was made.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$string = 'test text 12345'; 
if ($string != ($replaced = preg_replace('/text/', 'test2', $string))) {
    echo 'text was replaced';
}
```

Though if you don't really need preg_replace, you should use strstr or stristr.